# update column with condition from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a column based on the condition from another column.
something like this,
>

> Attire app |  SPV id | spv app
>
> ```
>     | test     |    
>
>     | test     |  
>
>     |          |     
>
>     |          |
> ```

expected:

> Attire App |  Spv id | SPV App
>
> approved   | test     |
>
> approved   | test     |
>
> approved  |          |    approved
>
> approved  |          |   approved

so, when column 2 is not null then update column 1, if column 2 is null then update column 1 and column 3.

here is my code :

```
        strcommand = "update tbl_Approve set [Attire App] = 'Approved', [Attire Date] = @ADate, [SPV app] = case when [spv id] is null then 'Approved' END where [attire app] is null"
```

on the visual I didn't add one other column named [attire date], assume that there is that column in the visual.
but it doesn't work, it's only update column 1...
do you have any suggestion about this problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't follow your code because it uses different column names from the description.  However, the logic that you want is:

```
update yourtable
    set col1 = @COL1,
        col3 = (case when col2 = '' or col2 is null then @COL3 else col3 end);
```

Notice the `else` in the `case` statement.  This sets the value of the column to itself -- so the value doesn't change.

Comment: Then perhaps `col2` is not `NULL`.  It might just contain a blank string or something like that.

Comment: what should I do to know the content of the column? it doesn't show anything just blank, and I also didn't insert anything into that column.

Comment: or maybe col2 has multiple white spaces, you can also add one more condition in your Case statement, something like...                   `NULLIF(REPLACE(Col2, ' ', ''), '') IS NULL` or I think even simpler way will be something like ... `REPLACE(Col2, ' ', '') = ''`

Comment: @M.Ali yeah... you were right... I only need to change null into '' ... and it's work now... Thanks a lot..